# Image attached next to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cursor

do any of you guys know of any plugins or examples of an image attached to the cursor.

For example:

http://www.beatport.com/genre/chill-out/10

when you click on a link a loading animated gif is attached to the cursor.

Thanks

Comment: It's called a 'tooltip': http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign onclick event to the links.

And the function called would create an IMG element, assign its SRC and CSS ( eg. absolute position, x,y coordinates based on cursor position ) , and make the image visible.

here is a similar working example :

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/simpleimagetrail.shtml

Answer (score 1):

you just need to create a absolute positioned image and update it's position on the mousemove event

Answer (score 0):

Its not attached to the cursor. Its just an loading overlay.

http://coderjournal.com/2009/11/create-an-attractive-loading-panel-in-jquery/